# XF Binding .. property not found but only with my Android application and not with iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the error message I am seeing in the Application output:

```
Binding: 'GearTapBtnCmd' property not found on 'Memorise.HomeTabPage', 
target property: 'Memorise.HomeTabPage.RightIconTapCommand'
```

**HomeTabPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:HeadingScrollableView
    PageTitle="Home"
    PageTitleVisible="True"
    RightIconSource="{DynamicResource GearIcon}"
    RightIconTapCommand="{Binding GearTapBtnCmd, Mode=OneWay}"
```

**HomeTabPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class HomeTabPage : HeadingScrollableView
{
    public HomeTabViewModel vm;

    public HomeTabPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm = new HomeTabViewModel();
    }
```

**HomeTabViewModel**

```
public partial class HomeTabViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public IAsyncCommand GearTapBtnCmd { get; private set; }
    
    public HomeTabViewModel()
    {
        GearTapBtnCmd = new MvvmHelpers.Commands.AsyncCommand(OpenPrefAsync);
    }
```

**HeadinsScrollableView.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:HeadingViewBase 
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
    x:Class="Memorise.Templates.HeadingScrollableView"
    x:Name="ContentPage"
    xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Memorise.Templates"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  >
    <t:HeadingViewBase.Content>
       <Grid 
          <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
             <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ContentPage}, Path=RightIconTapCommand}"/>
          </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
       </Grid>
    </t:HeadingViewBase.Content>
</t:HeadingViewBase>
```

**HeadingScrollableView**

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(InnerContent))]
public partial class HeadingScrollableView : HeadingViewBase
{
    public HeadingScrollableView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty RightIconTapCommandProperty =    
             BindableProperty.Create(nameof(RightIconTapCommand), 
             typeof(AsyncCommand), 
             typeof(HeadingScrollableView), 
             default(MvvmHelpers.Commands.Command));

    public AsyncCommand RightIconTapCommand
    {
        get => (AsyncCommand)GetValue(RightIconTapCommandProperty);
        private set => SetValue(RightIconTapCommandProperty, value);
    }
```

The warning message appears but the code seems to work. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing the warning message?

Comment: Probably because of the binding ```BindingContext = this;``` in your "HeadingScrollableView" class. Check [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/137235/binding-property-not-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How to avoid the "Warning"

Change the constructor of `HomeTabPage` to

```
public HomeTabPage()
{
    // Set the BindingContext before the page is created!
    BindingContext = vm = new HomeTabViewModel(); 
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

### Why the "Warning" occurs?

On the code you posted, when you create `HomeTabPage` like

```
public HomeTabPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm = new HomeTabViewModel(); 
}
```

what happens is that `HomeTabPage` is being initialized before you set the `BindingContext` for that `Page`... but the initializer does find a `BindingContext` for its base `Page` `HeadingScrollableView`, namely the one you set as

```
public HeadingScrollableView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

and thus, since the `BindingContext` is set to `this` what the initializer does is to look for the *path* `GearTapBtnCmd` in the *source* which is `HomeTabPage` or any of the objects it inherits from and it does not find it: then the "Warning" is shown.

Later on the `BindingContext` of `HomeTabPage` is set, and everything works as expected.

When you do as i suggest (set the `BindingContext` before the `Page` is initialized) `GearTapBtnCmd` is found immediately, and no warning is shown.

### Why the "Warning" occurs only on Android?

Sadly i have not an answer for that question, but it is noteworthy to see that the warning comes only when debugging, not if you rebuild the project (!). That means that the debugger for **Android**, which should be fundamentally different from that of **iOS**, is behind the warning... To find out exactly why this happens only in **Android** you could ask directly in **GitHub** to the **Xamarin.Forms** developer team... (and let us know if you find out).

---

But as for your question

> Does anyone have an idea what might be causing the warning message?

i think i might already have given you an answer :D